# Multiple PanPinchView in same container react-native

Tags: react-native

I am using the PanPinchView from react-native-pan-pinch-view. I want to have multiple of these in the same containerDimensions. Here is my current attempt that only shows the first one not all of them

```js
{views.map((viewobj) => {
  console.log(viewobj.id)
  return (
    <PanPinchView
      key={viewobj.id}
      minScale={1}
      initialScale={1}
      containerDimensions={{
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
      }}
      contentDimensions={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
    >
      <Text key={viewobj.id}>
        {viewobj.text}
      </Text>    
    </PanPinchView> 
  )
})}
```

NOTE: I am thinking that if i can get the location of PanPitchView and turn it into a view then do the next that would be okay too. Does anyone know how to get the location

Does anyone know any good movable pinch able and rotatables views with fingers for react-native (libraries or code)

I am creating my own library and got this so far

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Animated, PanResponder, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { PinchGestureHandler, PinchGestureHandlerGestureEvent } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export const RotatableResizable = () => {
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1);
  const [angle, setAngle] = useState(0);
  const [pan, setPan] = useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 0 }));
  const [lastScale, setLastScale] = useState(1);

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y }], { useNativeDriver: false }),
      onPanResponderEnd: (evt, gestureState) => {
        setPan(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: gestureState.dx, y: gestureState.dy }));
      },
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
    })
  ).current;

  const handlePinchGestureEvent = (event: PinchGestureHandlerGestureEvent) => {
    const { scale } = event.nativeEvent;
    if (scale !== lastScale) {
      const newScale = scale * lastScale;
      setScale(newScale);
    }
  };

  const handlePinchStateChange = (event: any) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === 4) {
      setLastScale(scale);
    }
  };

  const rotate = () => {
    setAngle(angle + 45);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <PinchGestureHandler onGestureEvent={handlePinchGestureEvent} onHandlerStateChange={handlePinchStateChange}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.box,
            {
              transform: [
                { translateX: pan.x },
                { translateY: pan.y },
                { rotate: `${angle}deg` },
                { scale: scale },
              ],
            },
          ]}
          {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        >
          <Text style={styles.text}>Drag me</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={rotate}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Rotate</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => setScale(scale * 2)}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Double size</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Animated.View>
      </PinchGestureHandler>
    </View>
  );
};
```

It works really well until after the first drop. Then it breaks really bad idk why (does not follow mouse)? can someone help?